# how to fetch value from URL and post in form M2

Tags: magento2, php, grid, xml, ui-form

I have product grid in admin panel where I have edit link too.  Edit link looks like

```
http://localhost:8888/backend/division/products/productedit/a_id/10/id/26794/
```

in ui form I need to send this id : 2679 as hidden field so that I can post it save it in database.

Can somebody help how can I do that?

Thanks